# Unable to boot Ubuntu server from USB. "Non-system disk or disk error"

Tags: boot, usb

I tried installing Ubuntu Server to a USB drive, because I want to use all four internal HDDs (that's the maximum) as part of a RAID5 array, so USB is the only option. This is a home server, so buying a hardware RAID controller is not an option (too expensive).
Here's what I tried so far:

- a 320 GB Samsung S2 Portable external HDD,
- a 500 GB Seagate drive in latter one a cheap enclosure
- a 32 GB Sony USB drive
- 18.04.6
- 20.04.4
- 22.04
- verifying the ISOs before creating the bootable drive

But the result was always the same.

The OS installation was successful (no error messages), but I got a "Non-system disk or disk error" each time. I did a test in VirtualBox, but got to the same the results.

I was able to boot from each drive with each release as a RAW disk, but not as USB (using Plop Boot Manager 5.0.15 in VirtualBox.

Edit: the PC I'm trying to install Ubuntu on does not support UEFI, although I don't see it as a requirement. I also tried 22.04 Desktop, but got the same result.

Edit 2: For testing purposes, I downloaded and installed Deepin 20.5. There were no issues during its setup. It booted from the external HDD on first try.

Edit 3:

1. I'm trying to install it on an HP Compaq dc5850 mini tower. I
   installed 18.04 on it before - to an internal HDD.
2. Here's the
   [list](https://pastebin.com/raw/vmcKVaHH) of ISOs I tried (with their calculated checksums).
3. I used Rufus to create the installer USB,
   but I managed to reproduce the issue in VMware Workstation Player and VirtualBox, so I'd rule that out. Also, there were no errors during the installation.
4. After the first unsuccessful attempt, I disconnected all other
   disks that were not the installer or the target.

Edit 4:

1. When using focal-legacy-server-amd64.iso, the installer hung after selecting/detecting the keyboard layout. I checked the ISO's cheksums and they didn't match. Unfortunately, I got the exact same result after redownloading and making sure the ISO is not corrupted by comparing the SHA256 and MD5 sums.
2. Using the mini ISO, I reproduced the original issue. It installed without any errors, I made sure to choose to write GRUB to SDA's (the only drive that's not the installer) MBR, but it didn't boot. The system boots in VMware Workstation Player using RAW disk access, but not when used via USB.

Edit 5: 22.04 doesn't boot on the target PC even from the internal HDD, but boots in a VM.

This thread continues at [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475954)

Comment: This video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utX08AxGEwo

Comment: That assumes a working system. My problem is that I can install the system to a USB drive, but cannot boot off said drive afterwards. I can set up a RAID5 array on my own.
I only mentioned RAID5 because it's the reason why I don't install Ubuntu to an internal HDD.

Comment: In order to help us help you, please: 1. Tell us more about the computer (or motherboard if home-built): brand name and model; 2. Which Ubuntu Server iso files did you try? 3. Which tool/method did you use to create the USB boot drive from the installer? 4. Did you try to install Ubuntu Server, when all internal drives were disconnected? (This ensures that the whole boot structure will be written to the target drive (the USB drive. Otherwise some critical part might be written into one of the internal drives, where it should not be.) - Please answer by editing the original question.

Comment: Maybe try installing from [the old style mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/) or [focal-legacy-server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/focal/daily/current/) would work for you. These should be able to install Ubuntu Server version 20.04 LTS, which will be fully supported until April 2025.

Comment: @sudodus  I've edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the details (in Edit 3). I guess that you booting and trying to install in legacy mode alias CSM alias BIOS mode. I know that some old HP computers may want an **MSDOS partition table** (not GPT) and also a **boot flag on the partition containing `/boot`**. Maybe you can try to fix that be preparing a drive with `gparted` (for example from the Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS live drive) before running the installer. (The boot flag can be fixed after the installation too.) -- There might also be problems with the driver for graphics or wifi.

Comment: It is also worthwhile trying to install from the old style mini.iso or focal-legacy-server according to the links in a previous comment.

Comment: @sudodus I'll try the legacy ISOs, however I'd rule out the problem with the computer itself, as I got the same results in my VMs as well. Also, that I used to run Ubuntu Server (IIRC 18.04) on this PC just internal HDD.
VMware Workstation has an option to boot from USB and I used Plop Boot Manager to boot from USB in VirtualBox before. And, in both cases, I made sure to not have any other drive connected to  the VMs, but one I want to use.
This PC doesn't have a wireless NIC and I don't really care about the grapchics driver either, since I'm not planning on using the system with a monitor.

Comment: Good luck with the legacy ISOs :-)

Comment: @sudodus I tried both ISOs and none worked. I added a new edit with the results.

Comment: Please try with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and use the **`dus-iso2usb`** method (via the mkusb-dus interface) and select **`boot-flag`**, which helps boot some old HP computers from USB. I hope it will work with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and the light-weight Lubuntu 22.04. but I am not sure if the `dus-iso2usb` method works with the Ubuntu Server iso files. But if you make Ubuntu Desktop or Lubuntu boot from USB, we take a big step forward, and the next step might be that I can make Ubuntu Server work this way too.

Comment: I don't have a working Linux system at hand, although I may have a Linux Lite VM laying around somewhere. I'll check mkusb out once I found the VM or reinstalled it.

Comment: @sudodus It didn't help. The installation completed successfully, but it didn't boot from USB afterwards.

Comment: I think you need help from more people because I am running out of ideas. The [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org) are good for complicated problems, because there will often be more discussions (compared to this question and answer forum). If you start a thread there, put a link to it here for me and others who would like to join the discussion over there.

Comment: @sudodus https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475954
I'll put a link to it in the details as well.